# Is view email context menu customizable in outlook 2007 add-in?

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I added event handler to `ViewContextMenuDisplay` to add a new button to view email context menu, which works fine in calender and contact view, but it just won't work in email view.

there happens to be a post about this topic here http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=3162, someone said that

> The fact is that Outlook doesn't provide events to customize the context menu of the selected text in mail inspectors.

is that true or am I using the wrong API? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its true, there is no event that allows you to customize the context menu email body. It is not exposed in the object model.